# How to get category name by category id in Magento

Tags: magento, categories

How to get category name by category id in magento on category page?
Thanks in advance please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use following code for category name by category id. Also get thumbnail etc.

```
$categoryId = 5;    // Change category id according to you or use dynamic category variable

// display name and other detail of all category                                   

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); 

echo $categoryName = $_category->getName();  

echo $categoryDescription = $_category->getDescription(); 

echo $categoryUrl = $_category->getUrl();   

echo $categoryThumbnail = $_category->getThumbnail(); 

echo $categoryLevel = $_category->getLevel();  

echo $parentCategoryId = $_category->getParentId();
```

Answer (score 0):

On category page, you can get information like this :

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
echo $category->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in Category Model.

```
    $Category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
    $cat_name=$Category->getName();
```